# Java compilation errors on lines starting with *

Tags: java, encryption

I am fairly new to Java and attempting to use the Java Crypto extension, so far I have this, except Eclipse is throwing errors on the lines with the *  and I'm not sure why.
I added in the *... they are not in the code normally.

```
private static byte[] getKey(byte[] paramArrayOfByte)

    throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
  {
    KeyGenerator localKeyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    try
    {
      SecureRandom localSecureRandom1;
      SecureRandom localSecureRandom2 = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "Crypto");
 *    localSecureRandom1 = localSecureRandom2;
 *    localSecureRandom1.setSeed(paramArrayOfByte);
 *    localKeyGenerator.init(128, localSecureRandom1);
      return localKeyGenerator.generateKey().getEncoded();
    }
   catch (NoSuchProviderException localNoSuchProviderException)
    {
      while (true)

 *    SecureRandom localSecureRandom1 = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
  }
 }
```

all fixed, copy and paste error on my part, the infinite loop was for testing.

Comment: Did you copy and paste the code? Where does the "*" come from? remove them!

Comment: the * is to symbolize where im getting errors. i put them there- maybe if you read the quest you would see that.

Comment: What error do you get. The variable `localSecureRandom1` is never declared. Since the method is static I presume this is a instance variable. Have you declared and initialized it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you introduced the  asterisks (`*`) to highlight the problematic lines:

- `localSecureRandom1` is not declared on the first line marked, and that should also be the message the compiler gives you.
- `localSecureRandom1` is then declared in the `catch`-clause, which doesn't make sense
- You also have an infinite loop in your `catch`-clause